# Backup app (Clash of Clans) data from the system partition; monitor app write activities

Tags: root-access, backup, file-system, partitions, twrp

Yes, I know I can backup my village via google+; yes, I've tried that before; no, it didn't work for me the several times I did it and I don't want to do that again. I've also used the Titanium Backup method until recently when it stopped working for some reason.

Apparently when I update Slimroms via TWRP and I wipe the system partition, my Clash of Clans village gets reset along with it, which leads me to believe that Clash of Clans is storing the ID for my village in the system partition. Is there a way to get that piece of data stored in /system and transfer it onto a newer build of Slimroms? Is there a way to monitor which directories an app writes to?

Answer (score 2):

What ever you do to update your ROM, you are doing it wrong. Never ever should you wipe your `/data` partition during an update (it should automatically wipe `/system`). Inside the `/data` partition is all your data, so your Clash of Clans village as well.
To backup and restore your village the Google+ option is working like a charm for me and all other people I know. Just remember to login with the same account you saved/linked it to and accept the warning about overwriting your level 1 village with your saved one.